# Exceptions & Interrupts

Tags: exception, assembly, terminology, interrupt, interrupted-exception

When I was searching for a distinction between Exceptions and Interrupts, 
I found this question [Interrupts and exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125394/interrupts-and-exceptions)  on SO...

Some answers there were not suitable (at least for assembly level):

*"Exception are software-version of an interrupt"* **But there exist software interrupts!!**
*"Interrupts are asynchronous but exceptions are synchronous"* **Is that right?**
*"Interrupts occur regularly"*
*"Interrupts are hardware implemented trap, exceptions are software implemented"* **Same as above!**

I need to find if some of these answers were right , also I would be grateful if anyone could provide a better answer...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interrupts are typically a method of signaling a change in hardware state.  Peripherals will be tied by electrical signal to an interrupt controller which prioritizes and assigns address vectors to each possible signal.  the interrupt controller forwards a detected interrupt condition to the CPU which may or may not 'interrupt' its present execution state to process the signaled state change (depending on whether interrupts are enabled and/or whether this particular input is non-maskable).  Interrupt conditions may, on some architectures, be initiated by software (such as on the x86 there is an int mnemonic) in addition to hardware input.

Exceptions span a greater range of implementation.  In some CPU architectures such as 68K, an exception can be similar to an interrupt but is generated by some CPU state that needs to be handled.  For example there are conditions such as divide by zero, illegal instruction, I/O bus timeout, etc. that generate exceptions.  By handling those exceptions one can do things such as emulate instructions and virtually extend the instruction set.

Exceptions may also be a software-only concept such as in the C++ language where certain error conditions can be trapped and handled.

So in general, the statements you are trying to find the validity of may be true or false depending on the exact platform you are applying them to.

Answer (score 1):

An exception as it is used most often is a form of control flow in a programming language to deal with events outside the normal logic flow of the program to avoid that the business logic of a program drowns in the error handling logic. The 'handling' of the exception is context specific. It is more like a kind of GoTo for a number of use-cases where it was useful.

An interrupt is a hardware assisted 'trap' to trigger certain actions when certain events occur, as a timer tick or program "calling" INT21. There is a handler registered which does something predefined.

Both may or may not be synchronous or asynchronous.