# software Interrupt vs software exception

Tags: exception, interrupt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interrupts and exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125394/interrupts-and-exceptions)

Can anybody explain what is the difference between software interrupt and software exception?

**Interrupt**: means time slice expires, call instruction strikes

**exception**: means access voilation,

I am right or can anybody explain in depth ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A software interrupt occurs when the processor executes an INT instruction.  Written in the program, typically used to invoke a system service.

A processor interrupt is caused by an electrical signal on a processor pin.  Typically used by devices to tell a driver that they require attention.  The clock tick interrupt is very common, it wakes up the processor from a halt state and allows the scheduler to pick other work to perform.

A processor fault like access violation is triggered by the processor itself when it encounters a condition that prevents it from executing code.  Typically when it tries to read or write from unmapped memory or encounters an invalid instruction.